# How to Update My CodeGenerator coded by Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding for aspnetcore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, vsix

I coded a CodeGenerator by Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.dll,i can use it in aspnet mvc 5(right click on the project and add -> New Build Base Project),but when i want to update it for aspnetcore,it does't work.
so what can i do for update it?

1.I tried to use visual studio sdk to rewrite it,but it was so....hard for me.

the CodeGenerator main is that：

```
 [Export(typeof(CodeGeneratorFactory))]
    public class ModuleScaffolderFactory : CodeGeneratorFactory
    {
        public ModuleScaffolderFactory()
            : base(CreateCodeGeneratorInformation())
        {

        }

        public override ICodeGenerator CreateInstance(CodeGenerationContext context)
        {
            return new ModuleScaffolder(context, Information);
        }

        // We support CSharp WAPs targetting at least .Net Framework 4.5 or above.
        // We DON'T currently support VB
        public override bool IsSupported(CodeGenerationContext codeGenerationContext)
        {
            if (ProjectLanguage.CSharp.Equals(codeGenerationContext.ActiveProject.GetCodeLanguage()))
            {
                FrameworkName targetFramework = codeGenerationContext.ActiveProject.GetTargetFramework();
                if (targetFramework != null)
                {
                    return String.Equals(".NetFramework", targetFramework.Identifier, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                            targetFramework.Version >= new Version(4, 5);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static CodeGeneratorInformation CreateCodeGeneratorInformation()
        {
            return new CodeGeneratorInformation(
                displayName: "[Platform]添加模块功能(Hplus)",
                description: "通过实体类，生成相应模块的Core层和Application层代码",
                author: "yanusosu",
                version: new Version(0, 1, 0, 0),
                id: "Yanusosu_Platform_Scaffolding",
                icon: ToImageSource(Resources.Application),
                gestures: new[] { "Yanusosu" },
                categories: new[] { "Yanusosu", Categories.Common, Categories.Other }
            );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to convert Icon to Imagesource.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="icon">Icon</param>
        /// <returns>Imagesource</returns>
        public static ImageSource ToImageSource(Icon icon)
        {
            ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                icon.Handle,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
```

please help me,please.or tell me the Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.dll can't use in aspnetcore and suggest me another way,so thanks!

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding` is for classic ASP.NET MVC. It won’t work on ASP.NET Core. You will have to look for a new way to scaffold code for that; you probably won’t be able to translate it that easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I found to resolve it, as a child class from you factory, the attribute export this as a .net core scaffolder, and the IConfigurableScaffolderFactory provides some feed back to Visual Studio Scaffolding.

```
[Export("NetCoreScaffolderFactory", typeof(CodeGeneratorFactory))]
public class ModuleScaffolderFactoryConfig : ModuleScaffolderFactory , IConfigurableScaffolderFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// evaluate a selected code generation context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factoryEvaluationContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsEvaluationContextInitialized(IScaffolderFactoryConfigEvaluationContext factoryEvaluationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// check selected code generation context is supported for selected project if yes, return true.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factoryEvaluationContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsSupported(IScaffolderFactoryConfigEvaluationContext factoryEvaluationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IScaffolderFactoryConfigEvaluationContext SetupConfigEvaluationContext(CodeGenerationContext context)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```